# Why my message prompt box is missing when I detect a car plates

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

This is my full code of the detection, the ocr_it is use to retrived the text and the save results should save the details of the car plates entering or exiting. But i tried to debug, not sure why only ocr_it function is called only. In normal case, i detected a car plates, if not registered a message prompt should show up, then the save functions will recorded as well, but now everything is not working.

```
# Standard libraries
import csv
import datetime
import os
import re

# Third-party libraries
import cv2
import easyocr
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# TensorFlow Object Detection API
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util, label_map_util, visualization_utils as viz_utils

# Setup Required Path
CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME = 'my_ssd_mobnet'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711' \
                       '/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME = 'generate_tfrecord.py'
LABEL_MAP_NAME = 'label_map.pbtxt'

paths = \
    {
        'WORKSPACE_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace'),
        'SCRIPTS_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'scripts'),
        'APIMODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'models'),
        'ANNOTATION_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'annotations'),
        'IMAGE_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'images'),
        'MODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models'),
        'PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'pre-trained-models'),
        'CHECKPOINT_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME),
        'OUTPUT_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, 'export'),
        'TFJS_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, 'tfjsexport'),
        'TFLITE_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, 'tfliteexport'),
        'PROTOC_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'protoc')
    }

files = \
    {
        'PIPELINE_CONFIG': os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'models', CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME, 'pipeline.config'),
        'TF_RECORD_SCRIPT': os.path.join(paths['SCRIPTS_PATH'], TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME),
        'LABELMAP': os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], LABEL_MAP_NAME)
    }

# Check directories existed
for path in paths.values():
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        if os.name == 'posix':
            os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        if os.name == 'nt':
            os.mkdir(path)

# Additional directories to create
additional_directories = ['Realtime_Images', 'Drivers']
for dir_name in additional_directories:
    dir_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dir_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
        os.mkdir(dir_path)

# Check if 'Realtime_results.csv' exists, if not, create it
csv_filename = 'Realtime_results.csv'
if not os.path.isfile(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Entering Time', 'Exit Time', 'Car Plate', 'Registered']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(paths['CHECKPOINT_PATH'], 'ckpt-16')).expect_partial()

# Constants
detection_threshold = 0.7
region_threshold = 0.6
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(files['LABELMAP'])
plate_times = {}


@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections


# OCR Detection and Filtering Function
def filter_text(region, ocr_result, region_threshold):
    rectangle_size = region.shape[0] * region.shape[1]

    plate = []
    for result in ocr_result:
        length = np.sum(np.subtract(result[0][1], result[0][0]))
        height = np.sum(np.subtract(result[0][2], result[0][1]))

        if length * height / rectangle_size > region_threshold:
            plate.append(result[1])
    return plate


def ocr_it(image, detections, detection_threshold, region_threshold):
    # Scores, boxes and classes above threhold
    scores = list(filter(lambda x: x > detection_threshold, detections['detection_scores']))
    boxes = detections['detection_boxes'][:len(scores)]
    classes = detections['detection_classes'][:len(scores)]

    # Full image dimensions
    width = image.shape[1]
    height = image.shape[0]

    # Apply ROI filtering and OCR
    for idx, box in enumerate(boxes):
        roi = box * [height, width, height, width]
        region = image[int(roi[0]):int(roi[2]), int(roi[1]):int(roi[3])]
        reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
        ocr_result = reader.readtext(region)
        reader = None  # Free up the reader object after usage

        text = filter_text(region, ocr_result, region_threshold)

        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(region, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        plt.show()
        print(text)

        # Add debug line to print whether the function is called or not
        print("ocr_it function is called")

        return text, region


# Function to check if the car plate exists in the 'Car_plates.csv' file
def check_registered(car_plate, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if car_plate == row['Car Plate']:
                return True, row['Driver Photo'], row['Valid Until']

    print("check registered is called")
    return False, None, None


# Function to check the car plate match the format
def is_valid_car_plate(car_plate):
    # Update the pattern to match your car plate format
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s\d{1,4}$')
    return bool(pattern.match(car_plate))


# Save Function
def save_results(text, region, csv_filename, folder_path, is_registered):
    if not is_valid_car_plate(text[0]):
        return None, None, None

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    formatted_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    car_plate = text[0]  # Keep the car plate intact
    img_name = '{}-{}.jpg'.format(date_time, car_plate)  # Include car plate in the image name
    action = ''

    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder_path, img_name), region)

    data = []
    if os.path.isfile(csv_filename):
        with open(csv_filename, mode='r', newline='') as f:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            data = [row for row in csv_reader]

    found = False
    for row in data:
        if row['Car Plate'] == text[0]:
            found = True
            if row['Exit Time'] == '':
                row['Exit Time'] = formatted_time
                action = 'exit'
                break
            else:
                row['Entering Time'] = formatted_time
                row['Exit Time'] = ''
                action = 'enter'
                break

    if not found:
        data.append({'Entering Time': formatted_time, 'Exit Time': '', 'Car Plate': text[0],
                     'Registered': 'Yes' if is_registered else 'No'})
        action = 'enter'

    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as f:
        fieldnames = ['Entering Time', 'Exit Time', 'Car Plate', 'Registered']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

    # Add debug line to print whether the function is called or not
    print("save_results function is called")

    return formatted_time, action, found


def show_message_prompt(message, duration=5):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hide the main window

    def close_window():
        root.destroy()

    messagebox.showinfo("ANPR", message)
    root.after(duration, close_window)  # Close the window after 'duration' milliseconds
    root.mainloop()


def show_combined_message_and_photo(message, photo_filename, folder_path, duration=5000):
    def close_window():
        window.destroy()

    photo_path = os.path.join(folder_path, photo_filename)

    if os.path.isfile(photo_path):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Driver Information")

        driver_image = Image.open(photo_path)
        driver_image.thumbnail((400, 400), Image.LANCZOS)
        driver_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(driver_image)

        image_label = tk.Label(window, image=driver_photo)
        image_label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="yes")

        message_label = tk.Label(window, text=message, wraplength=400, justify="center")
        message_label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

        window.after(duration, close_window)
        window.mainloop()
    else:
        print(f"Driver photo '{photo_filename}' not found in the folder '{folder_path}'.")


def exit_confirmation():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hide the main window

    result = messagebox.askyesno("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?")
    root.destroy()  # Close the tkinter window

    return result


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np_with_detections,
        detections['detection_boxes'],
        detections['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
        detections['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        max_boxes_to_draw=5,
        min_score_thresh=.8,
        agnostic_mode=False)

    try:
        text, region = ocr_it(image_np_with_detections, detections, detection_threshold, region_threshold)

        if len(text) > 0:
            is_registered, driver_photo, valid_until = check_registered(text[0], 'Car_plates.csv')

            # Save the results regardless of the registration status
            entering_time, action, found = save_results(text, region, 'Realtime_results.csv', 'Realtime_Images',
                                                        is_registered)

            if is_registered:
                valid_until_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(valid_until, "%Y-%m-%d")
                time_remaining = valid_until_date - datetime.datetime.now()
                days_remaining = time_remaining.days

                if action == 'exit':
                    message = f"Car plate {text[0]} exited at {entering_time}."
                    show_message_prompt(message)
                    if text[0] in plate_times:
                        del plate_times[text[0]]
                else:
                    message = f"Car plate {text[0]} entered at {entering_time}."
                    show_combined_message_and_photo(message, driver_photo, 'Drivers')
                    plate_times[text[0]] = {"enter_time": entering_time}

                if days_remaining < 0:
                    message = f"Car plate {text[0]} has expired. Please contact the security guard."
                    show_message_prompt(message)

                elif days_remaining <= 90:
                    message = f"Car plate {text[0]} has less than 3 months validity remaining. Please renew it."
                    show_message_prompt(message)

            else:
                show_message_prompt("Car plate not registered. Please contact the security guard.")

    except:
        pass

    cv2.imshow('ANPR', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == ord('q') or cv2.getWindowProperty('ANPR', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
        if exit_confirmation():
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: `except: pass` is an abomination.  This will completely hide any possible errors.  At least print the exception!

Comment: @John Gordon you're absolutely right! Remove those lines, run the program and get the output which is probably causing your issue.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Thank you all! I found what problem causing the detection issue. But why except: pass will hide any possible errors?

Comment: In a `try`/`except` statement it *tries* the code under `try:`, but if there's an error the code under `except:` runs. `pass` does nothing therefore the error gets covered up.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp